# Confused with Grid view OnRowDeleting Event?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, gridview

Today i was come to an issue when i was deleting a record on basis of  id from grid view and i used  OnRowCommand event for this.
here is my gridview code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridShow" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5"
            AllowPaging="true" ShowHeader="false" OnRowCommand="s_index" OnRowDeleting="gridShow_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RollNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnStatus" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my C# code :

```
 protected void s_index(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.CommandName == "delete")
     {
         oSRegisterBLL.BLLdelete(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
         gview();
      }
  }
  protected void gridShow_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
  {
  }
```

I successfully did this task by adding OnRowDeleting event on my grid view and definition of that event on my page behind but when i removed this first time i have come to known and issue " ASP.datashow_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'gridShow_RowDeleting' and no extension method 'gridShow_RowDeleting' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.datashow_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

I am confused with that why to add OnRowDeleting event on grid view with onrowcommand event ?
why i am confused because if i did not do any work with this event then why to use this event?
is there any way to work with only onrowcommand event ? or adding onrowdeleting event is essential for deletion of records from gridview?
I want to clear my mind for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your aspx markup of the `GridView` has declared the event handler here:

```
OnRowDeleting="gridShow_RowDeleting"
```

So when you try to remove it from the coedebehind you'll get that exception. So simply remove the event-handler and you can remove it from the codebehind.

**Edit**

Having a Delete-button, or even a regular button in a `GridView` with a `CommandName` of delete(which is the case here), will automatically try to fire `OnRowDeleting`.

So you have to add the event handler even if you don't use it or you have to rename the `CommandName` to e.g. `"DeleteUser"`, otherwise you get exceptions like *"The GridView 'gridShow' fired event `RowDeleting` which wasn't handled"*.

Comment: i know if i have to remove it from both sides, but when i do this i get error.
That is why i am confused.

Comment: @AmmarAsjad: I think the CommandName causes the event handler to be mandataory, see my edit.